# Как изменить/заменить текст в названиях

Tags: python, python-3.x, colorama

Как заменить цвет в first_name и vadim. Так как мало знаю в Python, реализовать пока что не могу.

```
from colorama import init, Fore, Back, Style

init(convert=True)

print(Fore.GREEN + '')

import time

a = input("Ждите ... Ввидите 1, чтобы открыть инфо..")
a = input()

if a.lower() == '1':
    time.sleep(5)
    print('\x1b[6;30;42m''[+] имя найдено!' + '\x1b[0m'
    "\n------------------------------\n"
    "first_name => : vadim\n"
    "\n------------------------------\n"
    )
    b = input("открыть фармилию ? (Y/N)")
    if b.lower() == 'y':
        print('frolov')
    else:
        print('error')
else:
    print('error')
```

Answer (score 2):

Используйте f-строки.

[Подробнее про f-строки](https://python-scripts.com/f-strings)

[Документация к colorama](https://pypi.org/project/colorama/)

```py
from colorama import init, Fore, Back, Style
init(autoreset=True)
a = input("Ждите ... Ввeдите 1, чтобы открыть инфо..")

if a.lower() == '1':
    print('\x1b[6;30;42m''[+] имя найдено!' + '\x1b[0m'
    "\n------------------------------\n"
    f"first_name => : {Fore.GREEN+'vadim'}\n"
    "\n------------------------------\n"
    )
    b = input("открыть фамилию ? (Y/N)")
    if b.lower() == 'y':
        print('frolov')
    else:
        print('error')
else:
    print('error')
```

Comment: Сделал дубликат строки f"first_name => : {Fore.GREEN+'vadim'}\n",  то есть получается на выходе так:

f"first_name => : {Fore.GREEN+'vadim'}\n"
f"first_name => : {Fore.GREEN+'vadim'}\n"

Почему не 2 строку не распространяется свойство цвета?

Comment: @Booblik потому что в методе `init` стоит атрибут `autoreset`.